# ubuntu 14.04 network adapter Atheros Killer E2400

Tags: networking

Please.
After installing ubuntu I do not have computer internet access. The system can not see my network card, how to install?
Nowhere on the internet is not any solution that would work.

My motherboard is MSI H170 Gaming M3 and onboard network adapter is Killer E2400.

Answer (score 0):

### I used this

modprobe alx

### echo 1969 e0a1 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/alx/new_id

from another thread with the same issue

### here --> [Is there any way to install Atheros e2400 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers)

For future questions please check the askubuntu site for similar questions (preferably ones labeled [solved]) before you ask a question.