# MSI Z170A Gaming M5 with Linux (dual-boot)

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, msi

I've bought the **MSI Z170A Gaming M5** motherboard for my new Skylake build (planning to set-up my new gear this week-end). As OS, I want to dual-boot to Windows 7 and Ubuntu (KUbuntu more precisely). 
At no point did I think there would be an issue with Linux and this MB, but I found some threads/reviews where people were complaining either about the UEFI booting or about not supported drivers for Killer 2400 network card.
My current set-up is a dual-boot win7 with ubuntu, but it's a pre UEFI era, so I have no issues with not supported drivers or booting.

In a nutshell, my questions are:

1. Will I be able to safely dual-boot to win7 and my choice of Linux distro?
2. Will Ubuntu detect my Killer 2400 network card out of the box?

cheers.

P.S. I found this question regarding [E2400 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers) but I am a bit puzzled how can one do **sudo apt-get install** when the network card is not working....

**Edit 1**: First part done. Set up the PC and successfully installed win 7. It wasn't as easy as it should though, due to the fact the z170 chipset has some issues with win 7 installation:

> Microsoft is removing support for the EHCI host controller (USB 2.0
>   spec) and keeping only the xHCI host controller spec

Anyway, that's as far as I got. Did boot into Kubuntu live DVD, and confirmed that internet is running, so the E2400 network card at least is supported.

Tonight I'll fire off the installation and hopefully I'll have dual-boot without issues.

**Edit 2**: I finally did it. I have now dual boot with Win7 and Ubuntu (yes, I remained on Ubuntu and didn't migrate to Kubuntu or even Antergos as I was debating for a while).

Comment: You can always get another computer, download all the debs from the Ubuntu Package Search, copy it into Ubuntu and do `sudo dpkg -i *debfile name*`. Make sure to look for dependencies. That's what I did when I removed `networkmanager`.

Comment: Also, If you can't dual-boot Ubuntu for some reason, try rEFInd. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: A workaround for the E2400 is to get a wifi dongle and use it, or just manually grab all the debs from the repo and git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/376851) ! So it looks like the newest kernel has added the device ID for Killer E2400 network card.

Comment: Not sure if Ubuntu has added the latest kernel.

Comment: From the question I've linked to my original post, the guy is commenting: "FYI - worked out of the box on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10". And anyway, in worst case scenario, I will have to download and install the new kernel manually.

Comment: Especially when there is no internet connection...

Comment: well, good that I have other machines in the house then ;)