# Killer Ethernet 2400: no wired internet

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I have a Z170 Gaming K6 motherboard with a killer ethernet 2400. I have just installed Ubuntu but I'm not getting any internet even though I connected it with a wired connection to my router. I have looked around and found this post

[Is there any way to install Atheros e2400 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers)

and this link

http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/21-killer-e2400-in-linux-ubuntu-debian

but I get stuck on the first few steps.

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname-r)`
```

gives me the following error

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in you sources.list
```

Here is what happens when I use lspci:

```
sudo lspci -vvnn | grep Ehternet
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]L Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
```

and lshw gives me

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: Qualcomm Atheros
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
version: 10
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory: df100000-df13ffff ioport:c000(size=128)
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

ifconfig tells me

```
Link encap: local loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr:  ::1/128 SCope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:41936 (41.9 KB)  TX bytes:41936 (41.9 KB)
```

Comment: And what does `ifconfig` say?

Comment: Your device is covered by default in Ubuntu 15.10. Would you like to install 15.10 or may I propose another solution?

Comment: I would rather use 14.04 since I plan on installing a software (ABINIT) that has worked with this version before, and I have had trouble installing this software in the past with other linux OS. I have never tried it on 15.10 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you update the ethernet driver `alx`. [Download this package](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/15/backports-20151115.tar.gz) to your desktop. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.'

Then, go to the directory `<extracted backport>/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/` and make changes in files `reg.h` and `main.c` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers).

Now, back to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20151115
make defconfig-alx
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. We will probably have one more step.

Comment: I get the following error when I input your first line:
'code'(E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-generic)
'code'(E: Unable to locate package build-essential)

Comment: Edit on the way! Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  apt-get update doesn't seem to work since I get multiple "Failed to fetch"

Comment: Do you have a temporary working internet connection, by wireless, thethered or whatever means possible?

Comment: Not with my desktop. I have a working laptop where I currently use to transfer files through a USB

Comment: It will be lengthy and tedious to do so by transferring by USB. I recommend 15.10.

Comment: So I have upgraded to 15.10 and the drivers are working fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @chili555, I tried to follow your instructions. After rebooting I steel have no wireless or wired connection. Could you describe your "one more step"? Thanks.

Comment: @VeLKerr I suggest you start your own new question. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @chili555, Ok. I adjusted my Ethernet and according to this edited your post (please, review and approve if necessary). But WiFi still aren't working. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724477/adjusting-wireless-in-qualcomm-atheros-device-qca988x) is my new question about it. Thanks for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> E: You must put some 'source' URIs in you sources.list

It is telling you exactly what to do.

Add `deb-src` lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

And then `sudo apt-get update`.

However, it's not clear if you're going the correct way about it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I figured as much and I've been trying to find which sources I needed. I added your links, but I can't use the "update" command since it can't fetch those links. How can I work around this?

Comment: I guess you would need to download the packages and copy them across or temporarily install another network card or device (such as an Android mobile phone). I don't think Ubuntu offer downloadable DVD ISO files, unfortunately.