# Connection to the internet via smartphone (usb-tethering)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, internet, android

I have a notebook **MSI GT72S 6QE Dominator Pro** with installed **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS**. This notebook has Atheros Killer E2400 Ethernet and wifi controllers. There are no drivers for they in Ubuntu ISO, so I have to install it manually (as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706071/killer-ethernet-2400-no-wired-internet)). To install these drivers I must have the internet connection, but I can't connect neither via Ethernet nor via WiFI.

Then, I decided to connect notebook via my phone **HTC Wildfire S** with **Android 2.3.5**. I connected phone to WiFi and then connect phone with the notebook via usb cable (usb-tethering). Then, I tried to turn on Internet connection:

```
$ sudo ifconfig usb0 up
```

but got an error:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
```

So, I got the new record in my Network Connections table, I still have no Internet.

[image]

How can I connect to the Internet to install all necessary drivers?

If you need some additional information, please write.

Comment: Don't run `ifconfig` manually, it will mess up the interface. You shouldn't actually need to do anything - just connect the USB, enable tethering on the phone, and NetworkManager will detect a new "Ethernet Network (name of phone)". If it isn't working like this, have a look at `dmesg -w` when you plug the phone in and turn on tethering - you should see `rndis_host usb0 ...` also check the output of `lsusb`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there is no way to use:

```
ifconfig usb0 up
```

By the way, I had the same problem, so I have had just looked around and I have been confronted with a wonderful Android App, which is EasyTether. at its called it is super easy, just follow up the instruction to come up with it.
have fun