# Ethernet not working on Ubuntu 14.04 in Alienware 17 R3

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

Ethernet not working on Ubuntu 14.04 server version in Alienware 17 R3. But its fine on windows 10. Probably some driver issue. Can someone help me over this..

[image]

Tried this.. [Is there any way to install Atheros e2400 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers) and it didn't work for me..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the response..I have included the image of the output for the mentioned command

Comment: Please next time provide outputs as text, not as pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This question is a possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers and/or https://askubuntu.com/questions/706071/killer-ethernet-2400-no-wired-internet.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster for the reply..
I tried this (https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers)
but it didn't work for me..