# Impossible to install Killer E2500 driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel, compiling, make

Hello im posting this because im having problems to install my killer card. I tried this 
[Is there any way to install Atheros e2400 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers)
but when i do this step

```
sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install
```

terminal returns this:

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic'
  INSTALL /home/antonio/ubuntu-vivid/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.4.0-127-generic
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic'
```

I tryed to disable 'Secure boot' but problem persist.

Also i found this 
https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/alx
tried to use git repository but when i do the last step (`./make linux`) terminal returns:

```
bash: ./make: No such file or directory
```

So i tryed with `make linux` and terminal returns:

```
    antonio@ubuntuserver:~/alx$ make linux
Copying /home/antonio/compat/ files...
Updated from local tree: /home/antonio/linux-next
Origin remote URL: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git
This is a linux-next.git compat-drivers release

Base tree: linux-next.git
Base tree version: next-20180530
compat.git: compat-2013-03-28-4
compat-drivers release: compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5
Code metrics archive: h h h t t p : // w w w .bit.l y/H6BTF7
Copying compat/ ...
Copying include/ ...
Copying udev/ ...
Copying scripts/check_config.sh ...
Copying scripts/check_depmod ...
Copying scripts/compress_modules ...
Copying scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh ...
Copying scripts/modlib.sh ...
Copying scripts/update-initramfs ...
Copying scripts/skip-colors ...
Copying .compat_base ...
Copying .compat_base_tree ...
Copying .compat_base_tree_version ...
Copying .compat_version ...
Copying config.mk ...
Copying patches/unified-drivers/network/0001-backport-alx.patch ...

Synched with compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5
patching file alx_main.c
make -C target/linux/
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/antonio/alx/target/linux'
./scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh /home/antonio/alx/target/linux/.config /home/antonio/alx/target/linux/config.mk > include/linux/compat_autoconf.h
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/build M=/home/antonio/alx/target/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic'
/home/antonio/alx/target/linux/config.mk:21: *** "ERROR: compat-drivers by default supports kernels >= 2.6.24, try enabling only one driver though".  Stop.
Makefile:1437: recipe for target '_module_/home/antonio/alx/target/linux' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/antonio/alx/target/linux] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic'
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'linux' failed
make[1]: *** [linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/antonio/alx/target/linux'
target/linux/port.mk:36: recipe for target 'linux' failed
make: *** [linux] Error 2
```

and if i try with the second solution (install compat drivers) terminal returns this

```
      antonio@ubuntuserver:~/Escritorio/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u$ ./scripts/driver-select alx
Processing new driver-select request...
Backing up makefile: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/Makefile.bk
Backing up makefile: drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/Makefile.bk
antonio@ubuntuserver:~/Escritorio/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u$ sudo make install[sudo] password for antonio: 

Warning:
You may or may not need to update your initramfs, you should if
any of the modules installed are part of your initramfs. To add
support for your distribution to do this automatically send a
patch against ./scripts/update-initramfs. If your distribution does not require this
send a patch against the '/usr/bin/lsb_release -i -s': "Ubuntu"
tag for your distribution to avoid this warning.

make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/build M=/home/antonio/Escritorio/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic'
/home/antonio/Escritorio/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/config.mk:21: *** "ERROR: compat-drivers by default supports kernels >= 2.6.24, try enabling only one driver though".  Stop.
Makefile:1437: recipe for target '_module_/home/antonio/Escritorio/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/antonio/Escritorio/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic'
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I also tried with this:

[Killer Ethernet 2400: no wired internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706071/killer-ethernet-2400-no-wired-internet)

But when i do `make defconfig-alx` terminal returns:

```
antonio@ubuntuserver:~/Escritorio/backports-20151115$ make defcongfig-alx
Generating local configuration database from kernel ... done.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'defcongfig-alx'.  Stop.
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'defcongfig-alx' failed
make: *** [defcongfig-alx] Error 2
```

My kernel version is `Linux ubuntuserver 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 19 10:58:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Ubuntu detects this: `Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)`

Please i really need help. Thank you