# Install atheros e2600 drivers?

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, ethernet, atheros

I have got a laptop on ubuntu 16.04 and I can't configure the ethernet card ...
I don't have wifi and ethernet connexion...
I believe that it is a atheros e2600 but I am not sure.

when I type modinfo alx I have this :

```
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     25B6ABE36E6CB50C1A7E6DF
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions'
```

If I do lspci -nn I have this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Inter Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
```

I have download linux-firmware_1.127.22_all.deb and installed doing:
sudo dpkg -i  linux-firmware____.deb

I have tried this solution as weel:
[[Is there any way to install Atheros e2400 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers/674103#674103][1])

without success either.

I added : 
`enter code #define ALX_DEV_ID_E2600                0xe0b1`
in reg.h
and :

```
{ PCI_VDEVICE(ATTANSIC, ALX_DEV_ID_E2600),  .driver_data = ALX_DEV_QUIRK_MSI_INTX_DISABLE_BUG },
```

in main.c

but when I do

```
`make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

(when I am in /ubuntu-xenial/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx, is that where I should do it ?)
I don't have any error.
(make entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic etc ... and then make leaving directory same one)

but when I do :

```
sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install
```

I have an error:
"no such file: bss_file.c:178 sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem no such file or directory".

any Idea ?

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to

```
sudo modprobe alx
echo '1969 e0b1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/alx/new_id
```

Then the ethernet should function so you can install the 4.8 kernel with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Reboot

If `uname -a` shows that you have x86_64 kernel you can download the following package using a computer with internet access

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic_4.8.0-41.44~16.04.1_amd64.deb

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic_4.8.0-41.44~16.04.1_amd64.deb

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe/linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04_4.8.0.41.12_amd64.deb

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-headers-4.8.0-41_4.8.0-41.44~16.04.1_all.deb

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe/linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04_4.8.0.41.12_amd64.deb

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe/linux-generic-hwe-16.04_4.8.0.41.12_amd64.deb

Copy them to the Desktop of the Ubuntu computer, then in terminal

`cd Desktop`

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

It should install the 4.8 kernel files, reboot when finished

Comment: I tried this solution without success. there was no error message, but I still don't have internet.

Comment: Does `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` show module in use alx?  Does `lshw -c net` show ethernet as UNCLAIMED?

Comment: The first two lines worked for me on e2500 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked for me, for Killer E2500, on Kubuntu 16.04.3 with 4.4.0-112-generic kernel. I could have upgraded the kernel (had wireless) but did not know *which kernel* would have support for Killer E2500...

Answer (score 1):

In the case of both your ethernet and wireless, there is no support in kernel version 4.4.0-xx. You are running 4.4.0-31-generic.

There is full support for *both* in kernel version 4.8.0-xx which is the default in Ubuntu 16.10. I suggest that you download and install 16.10 where both devices will work.

If you prefer another more difficult and cumbersome solution, please tell us and I will amend my answer.

Comment: Maybe install 4.8 to 16.04?

Comment: Yes, indeed, @Pilot6, however, that requires downloading and transferring several packages on a USB and that's why I considered it cumbersome.

Comment: what package should I download and transfer ?

Comment: @p.deman Please start your own new question and include the result of: `uname -r` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` Thanks.